SQL to update rows with reordered priority ID in order after deleting few records in-between
sample data/table is in the below SQL playground.
https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=ecc05c23-cfa4-4546-9334-5286b88eb2a3
screenshot of the table below enter image description here

Scenario- In this table there are 2 template Ids and for each template Ids there are 3 rule records. For each template Ids, the associated rules have priority in ascending order. Using below query , I fetch template Ids, where any of the rules' creation date passed 1 week and I get the below template Ids
SELECT template_id, *
FROM TestRule 
WHERE create_date < DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())

I get rule Id, 2 and 5 and I delete it.
After deletion, the priority of the rules will be like below
rule id  template id  priority
-------------------------------
1         100          1
3         100          3
4         200          1
6         200          3

I want to reset the priorities based on the current order so that the priorities will be 1 and 2 instead of 1 and 3 for each template. I can do that by fetching data in the backend service and update priority but looking for a solution in SQL for better efficiency. I did some research in the net to solve the issue but could not find similar problem addressed. I use SQL Server.

Side note, SQL Server 2008 reached end of life over 5 years ago. You urgently need to get onto a supported version.

Questions need to be self contained and include all relevant data - not require us to visit external sites

Also please do not use images. Use table markdown.

Appreciate that while certain priority values may be deleted, the overall rankings should remain the same.  So, you could just use the RANK() window function to view your data the way you want:
SELECT RuleID, template_id,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY template_id ORDER BY priority) priority
FROM TestRule
ORDER BY RuleID, priority;

If you really did want to do a formal update, then you could use an updatable CTE, again with the help of the RANK() function:
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY template_id ORDER BY priority) rnk
    FROM TestRule
)

UPDATE cte
SET priority = rnk;


Would that be DENSE_RANK?

@tinazmu In the absence of duplicates, both RANK() and DENSE_RANK() should behave identically.  Actually, ROW_NUMBER() should also work here.
